# The package contents are not updating during Export Release Build

Tags: flash-builder

I am trying to export my project using Flash Builder and the package contents are not updating. I have tried using Project > Clean and it is not updating the contents.

[image]

tags: export release build, package contents, package setttings

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had to refresh the directory. I clicked on the Project and selected Refresh.